# Does JAXB support reading xml tags dynamcally

Tags: jaxb, xml-parsing

Is there any method in jaxb to read the xml tags dynamically.For example i have two xml files both have diffrent tagnames and attributes.I want to read these two xml files using a single method.I don want to use getelementByTagname and all.All i need to read the xml tags dynamically.Does JAXB support this or there is any other concepts which can do this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single `JAXBContext` that represents multiple models.  As long as the root objects are annotated with `@XmlRootElement` (or `@XmlElementDecl`) then your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will instantiate the correct objects based on the XML input.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html